# MongoDB FATAL ERROR: Out of memory trying to allocate internal tcmalloc data

Tags: mongodb, tcmalloc

I am running mongodb 3.2 on ubuntu 14.04 server 64 bit. The mongodb server keeps crashing. Whenever I restart the server I see this:

```
stop: Unknown instance:
mongod start/running, process 25687
```

Also on running mongo shell after this I get the following error in it:

```
src/third_party/gperftools-2.2/src/page_heap_allocator.h:74] FATAL ERROR: Out of memory trying to allocate internal tcmalloc data (bytes, object-size) 131072 48
```

It was not happening before on my system. How Can I correct this error? It keeps happening every 2-3 hour.

Complete MongoDB Log File : [Download Here](http://tempsend.com/42C05C766E/CF6B/mongod.log)

EDIT1: Added mongodb log file.

Comment: At least comment a reason for the downvote..

Comment: Please post logs from /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log.  What is the total memory, data size?

Comment: @Astro I added complete mongodb log file.